# Need Regex Which Accept positive Decimal (4123.7802) and Number (91) 'Mandetory Field' also '0' is Acceptable

Tags: regex

Example

Values Acceptable
0
0.00
23
43.672
1234.8732

Values Not Acceptable
-1
76.12345
12a.64
21.4b

Field is Mandatory (Cannot be blank)
No Character is acceptable at any place

Comment: @noob does homework for free. And more are coming...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Just practicing my Regex skills. :D

Comment: @noob: In this case, you seem to practice copy-pasting from previous answers - this question [has been asked millions of times](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex%20match%20floating%20and%20integer%20numbers).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Solving this one was faster than copy-pasting. P.S: ha ha :D yes but not from link you posted. I wonder why didn't you closed it as duplicate.

Comment: @noob You can always copy-paste from memory, sure :)

Comment: The question is unclear, and none of the regexes here - I believe - will work for OP because *No Character is acceptable at any place* means the regex is used in some live validation text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP2fM3/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
(?:\d*\.)?\d+
```